# Communication between desktop application and web frontend

Tags: html, architecture, go, websocket

My project can be divided into 3 components: Desktop application, Server backend, Server frontend. I am using websockets application-backend and backend-frontend communication. Frontend is single page application. Whole looks like this:

[image: application-backend and backend-frontend communication]

I need to implement communication between frontend and application (dotted arrow in the picture above). I am able to use backend server as a proxy, but it would be more useful to have direct communication between frontend and application so that backend resources aren't wasted.

Is there any way how I can establish direct connection between local app and web frontend?

PS: I am using Go for both backend and application, JavaScript for frontend and WebSockets for communication, but general architecture answers are welcomed.

Comment: What does a "server frontend" mean in this situation? Are you talking about something running in a browser on the same amchine as the "desktop application"?

Comment: "Same armchair scenario" (browser and application on same machine) would cover most usecases, but not all of them. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: backend resources aren't wasted -- what important thing backend resources are doing other than fulfilling requests of your frontend?

Comment: Guanxi: in this case I need backend just for authentication/authorization, no real work is done on server side, so its not just server resources, but also lag when communicating application-frontend through backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to the JavaScript Frontend from your desktop application? If so, I can think of the following options

1. WebRTC. It's supported by Chrome (and Opera) and Firefox.
2. Chrome Native Messaging, this only works for chrome obviously, sends/receives info from stdin/out of your desktop application.

Overall I think WebRTC might be a better solution. Both of the solutions require you to run your web frontend in a modern browser though, Chrome/Firefox.

If you have to deal with IE, I can only think of having your desktop application to run a local web server, and have your web application poll/post to it. Even then, you have to work around cross domain issues, and you probably want to implement some level of security around it, so it gets fairly messy.

Comment: I am interested especially in last solution. I can make local server in desktop application and take care about security, but I think I will have often problems with some firewalls... Just curious, how often do you think I will have these kind of problems? And how can I solve them?

Comment: If you are connecting to localhost, firewalls usually don't make too much of a fuss about it, however, you will need to sort out the cross domain issues too in this case: if your app runs on http://www.domain.com, then connecting to http://localhost will be considered cross domain. JSONP solves this issue. However, if you use https, it would become impossible, since you will not be able to issue a certificate to localhost. That's why I didn't mention this method as one of the bullet points, because it is actually a hack rather than a solution.

Comment: @QianQiao WebRTC would be nice, but a quick Google search didn't turn up any Go WebRTC client. Am I overlooking something, or are you suggesting he do WebRTC from scratch? I assume it's not trivial to implement a WebRTC client.

Comment: @TrevorDixon the WebRTC connection is between the desktop application and the web frontend, I'd imagine the desktop application is written C# or C++ or similar languages, there are WebRTC implementations in all of those languages available freely.

Comment: @QianQiao He says, "PS: I am using Go for both backend and application…" I take that to mean his desktop app is written in Go (CLI?).

Regarding, "However, if you use https, it would become impossible, since you will not be able to issue a certificate to localhost," couldn't he set up a domain or subdomain that resolves to 127.0.0.1, then get a certificate for that domain?

Answer (score 1):

This might work, but may take quite a bit of extra thought to do securely:

Have your desktop program run a web(socket) server on some arbitrary port *p*, then try to talk to localhost:*p* from your frontend.

Or you could try to do WebRTC between the browser and desktop app. A quick search turned up https://github.com/coreos/go-webrtc-datachannel, which is just a planning document at this time.